# How can I run a joomla project?

Tags: php, apache, joomla, xampp, joomla-template

I get a joomla template, but I can't run it.

I copy it to htdocs folder in Apache(XAMPP) and when I want to run it, return this :

"Restricted access"

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); // no direct access
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php';
```

please kindly advise me,

Cheers,

Mike

Answer (score 3):

See:

**[How to install templates](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_install_templates)**

That is how you should install the template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,I downloaded 5 templates, but they don't have admin page such as this 
"www.your-site.com/administrator/"

Comment: Did you install Joomla itself first?

Comment: @Mike Redford: Templates don't have admin page, it is joomla which has, from the admin, you should install those templates like told in the tutorial.